# Size of Union and why it gives back an 24

Tags: c, sizeof, unions

So here is the problem:

I need to know how big is union (or something like that im new to C, and if i would like to know how to learn more of C i would be greatful)

Union should give me back hmm 20?

It gives me back 24 and i need an explenation.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
union Zadanie {
    int calkowita;
    char znak[20];
    double rzeczywista;
}ZadanieU;
typedef struct {
    int calkowita;
    char znak[20];
    double rzeczywista;
}ZadanieS;
int main()
{
    ZadanieS z1  = {2,"Borys",3.5};
    printf("%d,\n %s,\n%0.1f \n\n", z1.calkowita,z1.znak,z1.rzeczywista);

    printf("Rozmiar unii: %d\n", sizeof(ZadanieU));
    printf("Rozmiar Struktury: %d\n\n", sizeof(ZadanieS));

    printf("Rozmiar unii Calkowitej:%d \n", sizeof(ZadanieU.calkowita));
    printf("Rozmiar Struktury Calkowitej: %d\n\n", sizeof(z1.calkowita));

    printf("Rozmiar unii Char:%d \n", sizeof(ZadanieU.znak));
    printf("Rozmiar Struktury Char: %d\n\n", sizeof(z1.znak));

    printf("Rozmiar unii Rzeczywistej:%d \n", sizeof(ZadanieU.rzeczywista));
    printf("Rozmiar Struktury Rzeczywistej: %d\n\n", sizeof(z1.rzeczywista));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The size includes padding necessary for alignment. `double` requires 8-byte alignment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sizeof(ZadanieU)` will tell you the difference between the addresses of two consecutive instances of that union in an array of that type.

On some architectures, `double` values are aligned on 8-byte boundaries, and the union contains a double so it will be aligned on an 8-byte boundary too.

The difference between consecutive union addresses would therefore be 24.